# La différence entre "chercher" et "rechercher"

Tags: verbes, synonymes

Comme le titre dit, c'est quoi la différence entre "chercher" et "rechercher" en terme de signification.

Exemples :

- si vous recherchez une mission.
- si vous cherchez une mission.

Comment: @Circeus yes, this answer is complete,  and answer my question.

Comment: @Circeus how I can mark my question as duplicate?

Comment: It will be closed automatically if enough people vote for it. I believe three or four votes are required and there are already two as of me typing this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Une petite *recherche* dans un dictionnaire donne la réponse :

- [chercher](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9C1904)
- [rechercher](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R0870)